# Picocli: Require certain parameters

Tags: java, picocli

Is it possible with picocli to implement the following?

**Valid:**

- -A (-B | -C)
- -D (-B | -C) [(-B | -C) ...]

(-A / -D are not required)

**Invalid:**

- -B without -A or -D
- -C without -A or -D
- -A with -B and -C
- -D with -B and -C
- -A without (-B | -C)
- -D without (-B | -C)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman, in my opinion this is a perfectly valid question given the domain of creating CLI commands with argument groups. The question is whether, and how, the library can supply the desired validation behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to use picocli's [argument groups](https://picocli.info/#_argument_groups) to get this:

```
[(-A |-D) (-B | -C) [(-B | -C) ...]]
```

... by creating a mutually exclusive group for -A and -D, and another mutually exclusive group (with multiplicity `1..*`) for -B and -C, and create a composite group of these two groups that are mutually dependent. Since -A and -D are not required, the multiplicity of  this composite group would be `0..1`.